# input text in plotly dash based on a RadioItem picker

Tags: python, callback, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a code where i use plotly dash radio item to pick from different tests ('weekness', 'std', etc.) The main code is shown below.

```
def plots(self,):    
        
        df_lists = self.df_lists
        plots_names = ['weakness', 'std', 'std_average', 'std_weak', 'p_mean', 'p_mean_average', 'p_median', 'p_median_average','range', 'p_range_average']
        colors = {'background': '#111111', 'text': '#7FDBFF'}
        from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output
        names = self.names
        app = Dash()
        app.layout = html.Div( children=[
            html.H4('Dieharder Tests Plots'),
            dcc.Graph(id="bar-plot",  style={'width':'80%', 'height': '70vh','display':'inline-block'}),
            html.Div([  # this Div contains our output graph
            dcc.Graph(id='side-plot', )], style={'width':'20%', 'height':'70vh','display':'inline-block'}),
            html.P('Test Description'),
            dcc.Markdown(id='test-explain',  link_target="_blank", ),
            html.P('Chose Plot Type'),
            dcc.RadioItems(plots_names, plots_names[0], id="plot-picker", ),
            html.P("Filter by test:"),
            dcc.Dropdown(names, names[0], id="test-picker", multi = True), 
           
                ])
```

Now, i want to display an explanation to the tests whenever one is picked using the radio item button. I am using the following @app.callback code: (note i am just displaying one text for the 'weakness' test)

```
@app.callback(
        Output('est-explain', 'children'), [Input("test-picker", "value")])
        def update_chart_info(picker_test):
            if picker_test == 'weakness':
                text = "This test counts how many weak results are there for each test for all rounds and return the number divided by the number of rounds"
            return [text]
```

however, i am not getting anything on the dashboard when i run the code. I mean, the code works for other callbacks (that are not shown here) however it is not working for the callback for displaying the text. I tried different dcc components, such as html and markdown, but still can't see the explanation displayed.
any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few issues that are probably preventing your callback from working as intended:

- you have a typo in your callback arguments and `Output('est-explain', 'children')` should be `Output('test-explain', 'children')`
- you mentioned you want the Dash app to update based on the selection from the `Radioitem` component, but `Input("test-picker", "value")` refers to the id for your `Dropdown` component, so you probably want to change it to `Input("plot-picker", "value")`
- you'll also need a condition in your callback for when the Radioitem selection isn't "weakness" – otherwise you'll get something like `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'text' referenced before assignment` whenever someone selects another radioitem because `update_chart_info` won't know what `text` is supposed to be (for simplicity, I am returning an empty string whenever anything option besides "weakness" is selected, but you can modify this as needed)

The following should work:

```
@app.callback(
    Output('test-explain', 'children'), 
    Input('plot-picker', 'value')
)
def update_chart_info(radio_selection):
    if radio_selection == 'weakness':
        text = "This test counts how many weak results are there for each test for all rounds and return the number divided by the number of rounds"
    else:
        text = ""
    return [text]
```

And here is a small working example:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output

plots_names = ['weakness', 'std', 'std_average', 'std_weak', 'p_mean', 'p_mean_average', 'p_median', 'p_median_average','range', 'p_range_average']
colors = {'background': '#111111', 'text': '#7FDBFF'}

## sample names
names = ['weakness','other']

app = Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.H4('Dieharder Tests Plots'),
        dcc.Graph(id="bar-plot",  style={'width':'80%', 'height': '70vh','display':'inline-block'}),
        html.Div([
              # this Div contains our output graph
            dcc.Graph(id='side-plot', )
        ], style={'width':'20%', 'height':'70vh','display':'inline-block'}),
        html.P('Test Description'),
        dcc.Markdown(id='test-explain',  link_target="_blank", ),
        html.P('Chose Plot Type'),
        dcc.RadioItems(plots_names, plots_names[0], id="plot-picker", ),
        html.P("Filter by test:"),
        dcc.Dropdown(names, names[0], id="test-picker", multi = True), 
    ]
) 

@app.callback(
    Output('test-explain', 'children'), 
    Input('plot-picker', 'value')
)
def update_chart_info(radio_selection):
    if radio_selection == 'weakness':
        text = "This test counts how many weak results are there for each test for all rounds and return the number divided by the number of rounds"
    else:
        text = ""
    return [text]

app.run_server(debug=True)
```

[image]